# Minimal JavaScript required to use Shadow DOM polyfilled CSS encapsulation

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to figure out the minimum set of parts of the web components polyfill at https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs I need to take advantage of the CSS encapsulation offered by the ShadowDOM polyfill. Do I need the full polyfill?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to polyfill Shadow DOM, you can use [ShadyDOM](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom).

To polyfill Shadow DOM CSS, you should use also [ShadyCSS](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadycss).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vanilla JS to work with Shadow DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM